# Does there exist a degree-$4$ polynomial such that $f(1)=0$, $f(0)=1$, $f '(1)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

This is a problem in abstract algebra about polynomials that I don't know how to answer. I know that $1$ is a a double root, but I can't get much more from it. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Not abstract algebra, but note that this is the ODE $f^{(5)} = 0$ with 4 boundary conditions, which means it is underspecified and has a 1-D family of solutions, as ChristianF demonstrates.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $1$ is double root for $f$ we have $$f(x) = (x-1)^2(ax^2+bx+c)$$

Since $f(0) =1$ we get $c=1$ and since $f'(0)=1 $ we get $b=3$. So we have a family of polynomial which satisfies condition.

Comment: Thank you ! I don't know why I didn't see it

Answer (score 3):

HINT: why don't you just write down a general polynomial of degree 4 and apply all the conditions required by the problem?

Answer (score 2):

assuming $$f(x)$$ is given by $$f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$$ then
$$f(1)=a+b+c+d+e=0$$
$$f(0)=e=1$$
with 
$$f'(x)=4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d$$ we get
$$f'(1)=4a+3b+2c+d=0$$
$$f'(0)=d=1$$

Answer (score 1):

First $f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$...
Now $a+b+c+d+e=0$, $e=1$, $4a+3b+2c+d=0$ and $d=1$...
So $a+b+c=-2$.
So $c=-2-a-b$.
So $4a+3b+2(-2-a-b)+1=0$.
So $2a+b=3$.
So $c=-5+a$.
So we get $ax^4+(3-2a)x^3+(-5+a)x^2+x+1$  for our polynomial.   $a$ can be anything...   other than zero...